# Error when trying to evaluate Markov Random Fields using mgcv::gam "mismatch between nb/polys supplied area names and data area names"

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, markov-random-fields

I tried to implement this [great blog](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/19/first-steps-with-mrf-smooths/) post by Gavin Simpson using data downloaded from the cancensus package, but I get the following error when trying to evaluate the `gam`:

```
Error in smooth.construct.mrf.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  mismatch between nb/polys supplied area names and data area names
In addition: Warning message:
In if (all.equal(sort(a.name), sort(levels(k))) != TRUE) stop("mismatch 
between nb/polys supplied area names and data area names") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have posted my minimal working example [here](https://github.com/SimonCoulombe/mrf/blob/master/mrf.R).  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Zoltan

Answer (score 1):

I know you already found your answer, however I had the same error and a different problem, so I'll post my solution here for posterity.

(Note: I used the `sf` package instead of `rgdal` and `spdep`)

```
library(sf)
sh_terr <- st_read("your_shp.shp", stringsAsFactors = T) 

neighb <- st_touches(sh_terr, sparse = T) %>% 
  lapply(function(xx) sh_terr$FSA[xx] %>% factor(levels = levels(sh_terr$FSA))) %>% 
  set_names(sh_terr$FSA)
```

Your neighboring object structure should look like:

```
str(neighb[1:5])
List of 5
 $ G0A: Factor w/ 419 levels "G0A","G0C","G0E",..: 14 15 16 17 21 22 39 49 50 51 ...
 $ G0C: Factor w/ 419 levels "G0A","G0C","G0E",..: 3 6 67
 $ G0E: Factor w/ 419 levels "G0A","G0C","G0E",..: 2 6 65 67
 $ G0G: Factor w/ 419 levels "G0A","G0C","G0E",..: 5 16 62 70 271
 $ G0H: Factor w/ 419 levels "G0A","G0C","G0E",..: 4 14 16 68 70 71
```

And your spline formula:

```
Effect ~ s(FSA, bs = "mrf", xt = list(nb = neighb), k = 41, fx = TRUE)
```

It's all in the factors.  `FSA` in your main data object of your `gam` must be `factor`, and your neighboring object structure should be a list of factors with as many levels as the TOTAL number of levels in your main data.

Answer (score 0):

Found it -- You must make sure that you don't have any polygons with missing Y:

```
shp <- shp[!is.na(shp@data$Y), ]
```

Comment: Not always the solution, sadly...  I'll keep searching on my side.